# Phpmyadmin http password security

Tags: security, https, http, phpmyadmin

1. Is my password sent unencrypted when using Phpmyadmin through http?
2. If not, is there any downside using http compared to https?

Comment: Maybe you mixed up http and https in point 2? If available, i would always use **https** to administrate your webpage.

Comment: @martinstoeckli: I think point 2 is valid, but there is a confusing double negative... "If the password is _not_ sent _unencrypted_ over HTTP then what's the downside of using HTTP?". The fact that the password _is_ sent unencrypted over HTTP answers point 2.

Comment: @w3d - Ahh yes, that sounds plausible.

Comment: @martinstoeckli - Yes. w3d was right. There's no need to answer 2. after the positive answer to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are connecting to phpMyAdmin through `HTTP` then your password (and all your data) is being sent **unencrypted**.

However, if the form you are using to enter your username/password is sent to an `HTTPS` script (even though you might be on an unencrypted `HTTP` page) then it is sent encrypted, but then you would expect to remain on `HTTPS` for the duration of your session.

Answer (score 0):

Username and password are sent as plain text during login. After this they are sent in encrypted format in cookies.

You can check this using LiveHTTP Headers plugin in Firefox for example.

Comment: I didn't have enough reputation to answer my own question earlier. But here it is!

Comment: I think it is more likely to be a session cookie you are seeing, rather than an "encrypted" username/password.

Comment: It might be, but why is there fields for username and password in the cookie? It doesn't seem necessary for a session cookie. These cookie field names could imply that username and password is sent encrypted during the session.

`pma_mcrypt_iv=...
pmaUser-1=...
pmaPass-1=...`

There's also a field `phpMyAdmin=...` which has Expires value `Session`.

Comment: Hhmm curious, I guess this may be dependent on the setup/phpMyAdmin version but I don't see `pmaUser` or `pmaPass` cookies being passed on my system.

Comment: Hmm... I don't have more time to investigate this. I'm still not sure what is the right answer though.

Comment: @w3d, Actually username and password are stored encrypted in cookies. Only the private encryption key is stored on the server in the session. The username/password are then decrypted on every request after you log in. If the database login credentials were stored on the server, anyone who managed to hack the session database would also get access to the credentials of any user that logs in. Storing it encrypted in a cookie is really the only way to prevent this, besides forcing the user to re-login on every request, which is obviously not feasable.